# How to do language-specific matching dynamically?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Given the following inputs:

- a file with a mix of words from several different languages, one word in a line
- a locale string ex: `en_us`/`en_US.ISO8859-1` or `de_de`/`de_DE.ISO8859-1`

Example of an input file is:

```py
Happiness
Glück
幸福
счастье
Question
вопрос
spørgsmål
câu hỏi
```

The output desired is only those words in which ALL characters match the locale.

Example:
If the locale string input is `en_us`/`en_US.ISO8859-1`, for the above input file, the output should only be:

```py
Happiness
Question
```

Is this possible at all in python ?

The only closest thing I found was to do the Regex with `[\w]*` and supply the `LOCALE` flag. But that doesnt work and the python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) says: 'The use of this "LOCALE" flag is discouraged in Python 3 as the locale mechanism is very unreliable, it only handles one “culture” at a time, and it only works with 8-bit locales. Unicode matching is already enabled by default in Python 3 for Unicode (str) patterns, and it is able to handle different locales/languages.'

Comment: `in which ALL characters match the locale` you realize there are characters _common_  to all languages ? I think _locale_ is more a representation of dates, time, currency and punctuation variations.

Comment: @sln : Yes, I do understand that. The output for a given locale is not expected to be mutually exclusive from outputs for others.

Comment: I don't think there is a regex specification for locale It's something you have make yourself.

Comment: @sln: Does your suggestion remain the same, even if we remove the "dynamically" part of the question ? That is: Is there a way in Python regex module to specifically match characters from a fixed locale ?

Comment: I think that locale is mapped from a code page. Where I don't know of any regex constructs that can do that. But, it could, I just don't know enough about it.